# SystemExit: 2 : argpase parse_args() error on running pytest

Tags: python, pytest, argparse

I'm writing a constructor in a class `DungeonGenerator` to get the arguments' values from the command line via `argparse`. The environment for coding is VSCode and a simple Ubuntu terminal.

Here is the class in the file `generation.py`

```
import argparse

class DungeonGenerator:
    def __init__(self, params: argparse.Namespace) -> None:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

        parser.add_argument('width', type = int)
        parser.add_argument('height', type = int)

        parser.add_argument('--rooms', type = int, required = False, default = 5)
        parser.add_argument('--seed', type = int, required = False)

        parser.add_argument('--minwidth', type = int, required = False, default = 4)
        parser.add_argument('--maxwidth', type = int, required = False, default = 8)

        parser.add_argument('--minheight', type = int, required = False, default = 4)
        parser.add_argument('--maxheight', type = int, required = False, default = 8)

        parser.add_argument('--openings', type = int, required = False, default = 2)
        parser.add_argument('--hard', type = bool, required = False, default = False)

        # For testing purpose (to avoid pytest error)
        parser.add_argument('--capture')
        parser.add_argument('-v')

        self._args = parser.parse_args()
        print(vars(self._args))
```

I run the script with `python3 generation.py 10 10` and print `vars(self._args)`. (And so I am able to get each value from each key in the `dict`.)

It looks like this as I expected: `{'width': 10, 'height': 10, 'rooms': 5, 'seed': None, 'minwidth': 4, 'maxwidth': 8, 'minheight': 4, 'maxheight': 8, 'openings': 2, 'hard': False, 'capture': None, 'v': None}`.

But the problem starts here: after that, I tried to test my code using the test provided: `test.py` file in the same directory.
The script is run with the command `pytest --capture=tee-sys -v test.py`.

The part of the script for the test is:

```
def __make_params(width, height, rooms=5, bonuses=2, seed=None,
                  view_radius=6, torch_delay=7, bonus_radius=3,
                  minwidth=4, maxwidth=8, minheight=4, maxheight=8,
                  openings=2, hard=False,
                  ghosts=0, ghosts_delay=2, ghosts_walls=False):
    params = locals()
    import argparse
    return argparse.Namespace(**params)

def __default_params(width=40, height=20):
    return __make_params(width, height)

def test_argparse_parameters():
    from generation import DungeonGenerator
    generator = DungeonGenerator(__default_params())
```

The test result showed:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________ test_argparse_parameters ___________________________

    def test_argparse_parameters():
        from generation import DungeonGenerator
>       generator = DungeonGenerator(__default_params())

test.py:189: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
generation.py:33: in __init__
    self._args = parser.parse_args()
/usr/lib/python3.10/argparse.py:1838: in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
/usr/lib/python3.10/argparse.py:1871: in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
/usr/lib/python3.10/argparse.py:2108: in _parse_known_args
    self.error(_('the following arguments are required: %s') %
/usr/lib/python3.10/argparse.py:2595: in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = ArgumentParser(prog='pytest', usage=None, description=None, 
formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True), status = 2
message = 'pytest: error: the following arguments are required: width, height\n'

    def exit(self, status=0, message=None):
        if message:
            self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
>       _sys.exit(status)
E       SystemExit: 2

/usr/lib/python3.10/argparse.py:2582: SystemExit
----------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------
usage: pytest [-h] [--rooms ROOMS] [--seed SEED] [--minwidth MINWIDTH] 
[--maxwidth MAXWIDTH] [--minheight MINHEIGHT] [--maxheight MAXHEIGHT] [--openings OPENINGS] [--hard HARD] 
[--capture CAPTURE] [-v V]
              width height
pytest: error: the following arguments are required: width, height
```

It shows the `SystemExit` error. It also shows that it required arguments `width` and `height` even though the function `__default_params` in the test file provided their values as `40` and `20` respectively. So I expected that this shouldn't have shown the error and fail the test case.

So every thing is fine when I check it manually but not when the class is tested. What should I do in order to solve the problem and pass the test case?

Comment: Why pass a `Namespace` to `DungeonGenerator.__init__` that you don't use? Typically, parsers are defined separately, with `parse_args` being called on script entry and the resulting namespace passed around, rather than `__init__` for any class defining the parser and using it.

Comment: Related to that expected usage, a parser that fails to parse its arguments doesn't just raise an (ordinary) exception in the hopes that the caller can do something about it: it literally exits your script by raising `SystemExit`. You can catch that exception explicitly, but I strongly recommend making `DungeonGenerator` independent of command-line parsing.

Comment: Testing `DungeonGenerator` should only involve passing select values *as if* they had been generated by an `ArgumentParser`, without actually going to the hoops of parsing a list of command-line arguments.

Comment: Creating `DungeonGenerator` includes doing the `parae_args()` which looks in `sys.argv` for the required 2 numbers.  There's nothing in the test code that bypasses that.